# How to get shipping address by shipping address id?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-address

I have the order object. From that I can get the shipping address id. Can anyone suggest how to derive Shipping address by shipping address id?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the order_address object to get the shipping address:

```
 $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);
// $shippingId is the id you get from order object.
$custName = $address->getName();
$custAddr = $address->getStreetFull();
$region = $address->getRegion();
$country = $address->getCountry();
```

or use

```
print_r(get_class_methods($address));
```

to see what are the methods that can be used on the address object ($address).

hope it solves your prob :)

Answer (score 7):

To get the Address from an order object you could simple do `$order->getShippingAddress()`

Assuming

```
$order_id = 123; // put your order id here
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

Then

```
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();
$custName = $address->getName();
$custAddr = $address->getStreetFull();
$region = $address->getRegion();
$country = $address->getCountry();
```

Comment: I've already solved my question months ago. Even though appreciate the response. +1

Comment: `$address` is empty when i use `$address = $order->getShippingAddress()` but when i use `$address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);` It returns the address

Answer (score 2):

Shathish has given you a nice and correct answer.

However, you can use the singleton method and a query:

```
$shimnetId = "1"; // use your shipment id: 

$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$query = "SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order_address WHERE entity_id='".$shipmentId."'";

$results = $read->fetchAll($query);

var_dump($results);
```

`sales_flat_order_address` contains both the billing and shipping address.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I didn't tested your solution. But I think developing according to the way the Magento has developed is better rather than using direct SQL queries in the source. Anyway appreciate your suggestion. Thank you